# Adobe CQ5: SSO without LDAP?

Tags: single-sign-on, jaas, aem

A customer of ours has just purchased CQ5 and would like to externalize all of its security.  We'd like to use an STS server for SSO and then leverage a custom authorization/attribute provider instead of the CQ5 repository.  Ultimately, we do not want to use LDAP in any way.

Here is how we envision this (some pieces already working):

1. User browses to CQ5 Dispatcher running in Apache
2. Apache filter redirects user to STS site where login is completed.
3. User is redirected back to Apache with SAML Claims.
4. User ID token is placed as cookie into browser. (everything is working up to here)
5. CQ5 captures that cookie based on the SSO configuration (working)
6. Problem starts here: From here, we want to call a custom authorization provider for the user's attributes, roles, groups etc...

We have tried to figure out how to do this and can't seem to find the missing link.

Do we need to create a custom login module?  Do we need to create a custom principal provider?  Do we somehow use the existing LDAP capability in CQ5 but have it call a custom class which leverages the external auth source?

If anyone here has any idea how to do this, their karma quotient would be full for the year if they could share it.  I'm not sure if this is a basic thing you do with JAAS or even where to put my classes after I've created them.

We've worked really hard on this so far and seem to be close, but we keep hitting dead-ends.

Thanks so much if you have an idea where to begin!!

-joe

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of AEM now include the [SAMLAuthenticationHandler](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html) which allows you to:

- Redirect users to SSO to simulate IDP initiated login, or
- Allow AEM to perform SP initiated login with IDP
- Specify attributes to take from the SAML Assertion and add to the user's profile node (not sure if you can use this for groups)
- Specify which groups users should be added to
- Set a cookie called `request-path` that will store the URL the user arrived at, and then redirect them to that location when they're authenticated (ie. deep linking)

This makes relying on the SAMLAuthenticationHandler better than using Apache to redirect. The current version of the handler bundled with AEM 6.2 does not properly set the cookie when using the redirect method, but Adobe does have an updated version that they can provide that will fix that problem.

I normally recommend that clients do not have their own authentication handlers developed inside AEM.

When not using LDAP, this does create an issue where users will not exist until they've logged in. Additionally, when your architecture includes more than one load balanced publisher, it is possible that a user may exist on one server [user synchronization](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/security/sync.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the google group for SSO details. Here's one useful post:

http://groups.google.com/group/day-communique/browse_thread/thread/72c235c83a501252/fba4d08a90487156?lnk=gst&q=SSO#fba4d08a90487156

Comment: Thanks for the direction... I've got the SSO working, but all the documents that I can find have the LDAP hooked up as a user attirbute/auth source.  If you want a completely external solution which does no use LDAP, it's hard to find any examples at all.  I joined the group on Google... thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will have to implement a custom LoginModule, more information here: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/deploying/custom-login-modules.html